# Add X-Auth-Token - C# HttpClient

Tags: c#, httpclient

I'm trying to add an "X-Auth-Token" as a header on  my HttpClient and I'm getting an 403 error forbidden when I make the request, which makes sense because I don't think my X-Auth-Token is being attached as a header.

How can I specify "X-Auth-Token" in my Header?

Here is the relevant code:

```
using (var c = new HttpClient())
{
    c.BaseAddress = new Uri(url); 
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear(); 
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json")); 
    c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(token);
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use the [`Add`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158900(v=vs.118).aspx) method to add the header.

```
c.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("x-auth-token", token);
```

The constructor for [AuthenticationHeaderValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh193732(v=vs.118).aspx) accepts a `scheme`. I'm not certain what that is but is likely to be on of these

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789031(v=vs.110).aspx